# How to expand the number of rows per observation in R

Tags: r

This is a really easy question but for some reason I cannot find the answer on R cheat sheets.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Number of People     Income Per Person
5                    800
4                    300
6                    200
```

I want to expand the number of rows so that I have one row for each person, instead of one row that just says, "Number of people." So, 5 + 4 + 6 = total of 15 rows. How can I do this using dplyr or tidyr?

Thank you! - New R User

Comment: ```setDT(df1)[rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)), df1$Number_of_People),][,
                        .(ID = 1:max(Number_of_People), Average_Income = Income_Per_Person / Number_of_People), 
                          .(Number_of_People, Income_Per_Person)]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `uncount`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  uncount(`Number of People`, .remove = FALSE)
```

By default, `.remove = TRUE`, i.e. it will remove the 'Number of People' column in the output